# How to do custom message box in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-toast, android-snackbar, android-bottomsheetdialog

I want to show a message box at the bottom of the screen there will be an image on the left of the message box and a message on the right as fillmaxwidth size if a success response is returned from the service. However, I couldn't think of any solution other than toast message, snackbar and bottom sheet.There is no button above the message box. It only comes out at the bottom of the screen and covers the screen completely horizontally and turns off after a certain time. It seemed like the most appropriate option to me is to show a Toast message, but how can I fillMaxWidth this toast message? How can I customize it for me?

Comment: You can check this code . https://github.com/tfaki/ComposableSweetToast/blob/master/composablesweettoast/src/main/java/com/talhafaki/composablesweettoast/main/SweetToast.kt

Comment: you can use a box composable parent in the screen and place your fillMaxWidth composable at the bottom within an if condition based on a boolean state, then simply change the boolean state to true to show and to false to hide the custom composeable